# SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

I'm working on my first Python/Django app and ran into the following problem:

My app maintains a booking calendar implemented with a `Calendar` model class and a `CalendarDay` model class. At one point for a booking I want to query the `CalendarDay` instances like:

```
dates = CalendarDay.objects.filter(calendar = booking.calendar, calendar_date >= booking.arrival_date, calendar_date <= booking.departure_date)
```

This generates `'SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg'` on the second and third argument. From the Django documentation I understand that you should be able to do this and that the conditions are AND-ed, which is what I'm after.

Alternatively, when I try:

```
dates = CalendarDay.objects.filter(calendar = booking.calendar, calendar_date__ge = booking.arrival_date, calendar_date__le = booking.departure_date)
```

I get a `FieldError: Join on field 'calendar_date' not permitted` from Django.

I've worked my way through the Django docs however -apparently- I'm missing something. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I ended up with the following solution:

```
dates = CalendarDay.objects.filter(calendar = booking.calendar, calendar_date__range = [self.arrival_date, self.departure_date])
```

Comment: Where did the django documentation state that that first syntax was valid? Because that seems very unlikely to me. The syntax `calendar_date >= booking.arrival_data` ends up at evaluating to `True` or `False` if both variables are known, hence you pass a boolean to that function without a keyword.

Comment: @KillianDS: Yeah, you're right. I reread the docs and it doesn't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dates = CalendarDay.objects.filter(calendar = booking.calendar, calendar_date__ge = booking.arrival_date, calendar_date__le = booking.departure_date)
```

ge and le are not valid, use **lt** (lower than) or **gt** (greater than), or **gte** (greater than and equal) and **lte** (lower than and equal)

(when you wirte le - Django tries to run sql join on field called "le" but the there isnt one, hence the error you get)

Answer (score 1):

For your first try

```
dates = CalendarDay.objects.filter(calendar = booking.calendar, calendar_date >= booking.arrival_date, calendar_date <= booking.departure_date)
```

`calender_date >= booking.arrival_date` and `calender_date <= booking.departure_date` evaluate to `True` or `False`. Hence you get the  `'SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg'` error on the second and third argument.

For the second try

```
dates = CalendarDay.objects.filter(calendar = booking.calendar, calendar_date__ge = booking.arrival_date, calendar_date__le = booking.departure_date)
```

SQL join is run on field "le" and "ge" but they not there.Hence you get `FieldError: Join on field 'calendar_date' not permitted`

You should use `gte` or `lte` which refer to greater than or equal to and less than or equal to respectively.

So you code should be

```
dates = CalendarDay.objects.filter(calendar = booking.calendar, calendar_date__gte = booking.arrival_date, calendar_date__lte = booking.departure_date)
```